# how to update a line from a file that I put in a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, file, user-interface

Maybe my title is not the best but here is what I really want.I have a file in which I have some lines.I have put each line in a `JTextField`.
Here is an example. Let's say this is a line in a textfield

```
mary peterson teacher
```

Now what I want is to modify this line in the textfield and save it when I close the frame in the file like this

```
mary ruble teacher piano .
```

Can someone please give me an idea about how to do this?

Comment: And what is the problematic part: retrieving the new values from the text fields or saving to file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you break the problem into smaller and smaller steps until you know how to code each step.

You first have to create a Java Swing GUI that contains a `JTextField` and a `JButton` that tells your Java code to bring up the next line of text.

Here's one way of breaking up the problem.

- Open input file
- Open output file
- Display first line in the `JTextField`
- On `JButton` left click, write line from `JTextField` to output file, read next line from input file, display next line in the `JTextField`.
- On end of input file, close input file, close output file.

Comment: all that you have written there i have done,the only part left is with the file update

Comment: @Laura: You can't just update the file you're reading because the number of characters in the line (and the file) will increase or decrease depending on the edits made.  You write a new file, and delete the original file and rename the new file, if necessary.

Comment: thank you.i'm new to java and i'm trying to understand how to do things.

Comment: when i read the file i put all the elements in an arraylist,and that is why i thought i could do this.

Comment: @Laura: You can put all of the file lines in an ArrayList, although it's not necessary.  But each String in the ArrayList is probably a different length.  When you edit a String, you actually replace the old String with the new String.  Strings in Java are unchangeable (immutable).